# signed the upgrade version of android with different certificate key

Tags: android, updates, code-signing

I had an application with versionCode 1 and versionName = 1.0 on PlayStore.I decided to upgrade my app to versionCode 2 and versionName 1.1.However by mistake I signed it with different certificate key.

Developers android documentation mentions that if the application is upgraded with different certificate key then users will not be able to upgrade it.Realising the horror I immediately shipped another upgrade with versionCode 3 and versionName 1.2 but this time I signed it with the original certificate key(one which I used to sign the versionCode 1 and versioName 1.0).

My question is will users who installed initial version be able to upgrade  now since I launched versionCode 3 with the same certificate key as their application which is installed in their devices with versionCode 1?

Comment: why did not you signed the app with versionCode 2 (with the original certificate).you could have deleted the app created with wrong certificate ( versionCode 2 ) and recreate the versionCode 2 with proper certificate.

Comment: When you submit you apk with versionCode 2 and versionName 1.1 using different certificate key it will allow you to upload apk i think which is not allowed you to upload apk with different certificate key so you can upload your apk with  with versionCode 2 and versionName 1.1 using correct certificate key.

Comment: @turtle,once we upload apk on play store we can not delete apk from play store we just unpublished it.

Comment: Yes you are correct @HareshChhelana , it cannot be undone.BTW i was trying to explain the same you did ( seems like i made a complex comment above ).

Comment: @HareshChhelana - yes I get your point.It allowed me to upload my apk.I do not completely remember if I signed with correct certificate key or not.That's why to be safe I uploaded another version with the original certificate key.

Comment: However my question now is will the users get the update now since the certificate key matches with the original apk which is installed in their devices

Comment: @user3197388,Yes i think user get the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People who had v1 will have no problem.
If you really uploaded a v2 with a different signature and someone went through the trouble of uninstalling just so they could install v2 would have to uninstall again and install v3.

What i really wonder tough it's how you uploaded an apk with a different signature. I accidentally lost my key once and didn't find out until i tried to upload an update wich i had to sign with a different key and the console blocked me from uploading because it requires all apks to have the same signature.

According to the documentation if you ever lose your key you will never be able to upload a new version and if you still desire to then you must take down the first application and give your second application a different package name.

Comment: I use adt plugin for eclipse.In that I export the android application.Unfortunately another application of eclipse workspace had a keystore at different different location but with same password as that of my playstore application. I did not check the location of keystore and typed the password.It created new signed apk.But as most people say that playstore does not allow you to upload upgrade with different certificate then possibly I signed with same certificate key.But to be safe I uploaded another version with the original certificate key.

Comment: you could have tested that on a device (if you have one) installing v1 apk first and trying to update it to v2 using second apk. If it worked then both had same signature. But still... the console wouldn't allow you to upload an apk with different signature so chances are everything will be ok.

Comment: But the thing is I did not have version 1 in my phone. So I installed version 2 (the one with the wrong certificate key).Then when I uploaded version 3 with the original certificate key I did not get the update notification possibly because version 2 and version 3 have different certificate key.What do you think?

Comment: I was talking about using the apk file directly on your phone. But yet again if you installed version 2 and version 3 is already on the store then just try to manually update for yourself and then you'll know for sure. Getting a notification of an update has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks.I manually updated the application on my device(version 2) with the latest version 3 on play store and successfully updated it.If they both had diferent certificate keys then I would not have been able to update the application.Am I right? That means i uploaded the version 2 with the right certificate key.

Comment: Yes, Exactly. So every user will have no problem at all receiving the updates either.

Comment: But then why did not my device notify me about the version 3 which I uploaded on the play store? Why I had to manually update it?Other applications automatically update themselves but not my app.What's the problem?

Comment: Notifications are not handled instantly when an update arrives to the play store. You should normally expect somewhere around 24hrs for a notification to appear on the user's device. Depending on some factors it could take longer but sooner or later the user will always be notified as long as they have updates set to automatic on their device.